# Can't "print" with .innerHTML using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, innerhtml

I'm just beginning with Javascript and, well, this code is quite obvious and it just don't work and I don't know why, because everything looks fine:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is my first Javascript test.</h1>
<p id = "y">123</p>
<button type = "button" onclick = "do()">Do it!</button>
<script>
var x = ["First Element", "Second Element", "Third Element", "Fourth Element"];
function do() {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = x[i] + "<br>";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the bloody button, it just don't work. It does not give me the contents of the array on the < p > tag there.

I thank you very much!

Comment: `do` is a reserved word in JavaScript. You should choose a different name for your function. http://jsfiddle.net/3e3CN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done by this small change...

```
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML += x[i] + "<br>";
```

Also it would be wiser to have "y" stored in a local variable rather than getting it every time.

```
<script>
var y = document.getElementById("y");
var x = ["First Element", "Second Element", "Third Element", "Fourth Element"];
function do() {
    y.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y.innerHTML += x[i] + "<br>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I thank you for the tip (To store y in a local variable). I changed to "+=" and it's still not working. The y keeps its original "123" content when I click on the button.

Comment: just clear the innerHTML before you begin the for loop. `y.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: I'll give you the right answer because with the "+=" thing you solved a next problem that I had not foreseen. What actually solved it was the coment of Crazy Train up there. The fact that I was using "do()" for the name of the function screwed up everything :). I thank you very much!